# AES-256-CFB cuts off message when using `random_iv`

Tags: ruby, encryption

I have two scripts for encrypting and decrypting messages using AES.

Here's `encrypt.rb`:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'digest'

KEY = 'sekrit_key'
MESSAGE = "My Name is Rabbit and I don't know anything!"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CFB)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = KEY
# hexdigest the IV to make sure encode64 doesn't fuck up
iv = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(cipher.random_iv)
cipher.iv = iv

encrypted = cipher.update(secret_message)+cipher.final
puts Base64.urlsafe_encode64(iv+'|'+encrypted.encode)
```

... and `decrypt.rb`:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

KEY = 'sekrit_key'
encrypted_message = STDIN.read.strip

parts = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encrypted_message ).split('|')
iv = parts[0]
encrypted = parts[1]

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CFB)
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = KEY
decipher.iv = iv

message = decipher.update(encrypted)+decipher.final

if message.eql?("My Name is Rabbit and I don't know anything!")
    print '.'
else
    puts
    puts encrypted_message
    puts message
end
```

When I now continuosly run both scripts, My output is cut off quite often!

```
$ while true; do ruby encrypt.rb | ruby decrypt.rb; done
....
YmZhNDg2ODJjNGZiOGIzZTcyMzAwYzMxZWUwNWI0Y2V8w2aJk930EL3gh3rfQsd2B3xZKy5wjoCzlZoYHBgmv6m51ZwAWQHGtCJoNRg=
My Name is Rabbi
..
YjMwNDQxOGRjMjg4NGEzOThmM2IwNGFiZDBiZTQxZGZ8OfLyjGQGKV3PPUpCvfL08IDuk7M7d3w7fj6F5Rql94jkRdwaCuuMfedqtFk=
My Name is Rabbit and
..
OWUxYzFlZWU5MTc4NGZjYWYxYzZiOGEwOTBjOGMxYzJ8g7I4X_Dt6K9ufByMhLBGlpoYCv8vlR0lTBqP-zS647tmmFh81rXdR8T-UkM=
My Name i
....
# and so on
```

Why are so many of my messages cut off?

**Update:** When using a fixed IV in `encrypt.rb` (eg. substitute `cipher.random_iv` with `KEY`) instead of a randomly generated, the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you're treating binary data as strings. `iv` as well as `encrypted.encode` are binary and you're concatenating them with "|" (a string). Both `iv` as well as the message may contain the pipe character which will cause problems when splitting. In general, it's best to base64 both parts separately.

Here's working code:

`encrypt.rb`

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'digest'

KEY = 'sekrit_key123456' * 2
MESSAGE = "My Name is Rabbit and I don't know anything!"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CFB)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = KEY
iv = cipher.random_iv

encrypted = cipher.update(MESSAGE)+cipher.final
puts Base64.strict_encode64(iv)+'|'+Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted.encode)
```

`decrypt.rb`

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

KEY = 'sekrit_key123456' * 2 # key needs to be the right length
encrypted_message = STDIN.read.strip

parts = encrypted_message.split('|')
iv = Base64.strict_decode64(parts[0])
encrypted = Base64.strict_decode64(parts[1])

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CFB)
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = KEY
decipher.iv = iv

message = decipher.update(encrypted)+decipher.final

if message.eql?("My Name is Rabbit and I don't know anything!")
    print '.'
else
    puts
    puts encrypted_message
    puts message
end
```

Also notice that `random_iv` already assigns `iv` to cipher, so you don't need to (see source under http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/OpenSSL/Cipher/random_iv ).

Comment: That was the problem! In the script above I `hexdigest` the generated `random_iv` first before sometimes the script would complain about "IV too short" when decrypting. I assume the problem was the same. Thank you!